# Periodic Backups to a remote Windows Server folder with OS X

Tags: macos, backup, windows

I need a tool that will allow backups of specific folders to a remote Windows Share. The Macs connect via SMB or CIFS, meaning AFAIK rsync is out of the question.

I only need it to backup on folder, but having it automatic would be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

If the remote (Windows) filesystem is mountable in the Finder than any application that does file level backups should work. I use SuperDuper and have used Carbon Copy Cloner and Chronosync in the past with good success.

Note that CCC backs up to either a Mac filesystem or a DMG (disk image) file which may be problematic on a Windows PC with no Macs around.